# decision tree - customize plot title when using Rattle and rpart.plot

Tags: r, rpart, rattle

I created a decision tree using `Rattle` and the `rpart.plot package`. This package is supposed to make the output more "pretty" than the regular `Rattle` output.

Here's what the output looks like.

---

[image: image file containing Decision Tree with Title (top legend)]

---

**My Question:** I don't like how the default title (top legend) looks. How may I customize it (change the wording or font size)?

Update: Rattle is a GUI. So I didn't use any code to create the Decision Tree (I still learning to code in R). However, I went back and posted the following to PasteBin:

1. http://pastebin.com/NTFPsyfx , this is the Rattle ***log*** (this may contain the code used to generate `rpart.plot`).
2. http://pastebin.com/LmJs9Z5B , this is the ***text output*** from Rattle.

Comment: You haven't provided any code, so let's assume your model object is called `fit`: Does `rpart.plot(fit, main="My Title", cex.main=2)` give you what you need?

Comment: @eipi10 Thank you for mentioning code. I used Rattle's GUI, so didn't use any direct code. I have, however, updated my original post with 2 PasteBins containing the Rattle log, and the text output. I will try out your solution and let you know if it worked (may take a couple of days though).